# Count recalls from time data

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing the following information:

```
ID    ATTRIBUTE    START    END
```

I want to count recalls per `ID`. A recall occurs if

```
ID.i == ID.(-i)
ATTRIBUTE.i == ATTRIBUTE.(-i)
END.i <= START.(-i) - 100
```

where `(-i) := (j != i)`

Can you help me?

Thank you!

Sorry for not providing data earlier - here is some:

```
ID    ATTRIBUTE    START        END
1     10           2000-01-01   2000-01-30
1     10           2000-03-01   2000-04-30
2     20           2000-01-01   2000-01-30
2     21           2000-03-01   2000-04-30
3     30           2000-01-01   2000-01-30
3     30           2001-01-01   2000-01-30
4     40           2000-01-01   2000-01-30
4     40           2000-03-01   2000-04-30
4     50           2000-06-01   2000-06-30
4     40           2000-07-01   2000-10-30
4     40           2001-01-01   2001-01-30
```

should lead to

```
ID    ATTRIBUTE    START        END          COUNT
1     10           2000-01-01   2000-01-30   2
1     10           2000-03-01   2000-04-30   2
2     20           2000-01-01   2000-01-30   1
2     21           2000-03-01   2000-04-30   1
3     30           2000-01-01   2000-01-30   1
3     30           2001-01-01   2000-01-30   1
4     40           2000-01-01   2000-01-30   4
4     40           2000-03-01   2000-04-30   4
4     41           2000-06-01   2000-06-30   1
4     40           2000-07-01   2000-10-30   4
4     40           2001-01-01   2001-01-30   4
```

(did it by hand - hope there are no mistakes)

Comment: By `.1` and `.2` do you mean a comparison of row `i` with `i+1`. I.e. for adjacent rows, if the `ID` *and* `ATTRIBUTE` match **and** difference between END and subsequent START is less than 100?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I don't necessarily mean 2 = i+1 but just any other row. I'll correct this with -i notation

Comment: Still waiting for sample data for testing.

Comment: Now that we have data, can you explain why the COUNT for ID==1 is 2?

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines. Untested in absence of sample data:

```
aggregate(df, df$ID, df$ATTRIBUTE, 
      FUN= function(x)  sum( sapply(1:(nrow(x)-1), 
                              function(n)x$END[n] <= x$START[n+1] -100) ) )
```

After the edit of the question I still think there may be potential for the code above if the argument dataframe is first sorted by START within ID and ATTRIBUTE:

```
aggregate(df[ order(df$ID, DF$ATTRIBUTE, df$START), ]
        df$ID, df$ATTRIBUTE, 
      FUN= function(x)  sum( sapply(1:(nrow(x)-1), 
                              function(n)x$END[n] <= x$START[n+1] -100) ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `==` and `<=` doesn't make much sense, since the value on the left is a single value, but the value on the right is a vector.  I'm guessing that what you want is to test if `ID` matches any other `ID`.  For this, you can use

```
with(your_data, ID[i] %in% ID[-i])
```

To save you looping though, I suggest picking up duplicate `ID`s with the `duplicate` function.  E.g.,

```
bad_ID <- duplicated(your_data$ID)
```

The logic is even more ambiguous for the third condition.  I'm (wildly) guessing that you want the value of `END` to be less than all the other values of `START` minus 100.

We'll have to loop for this condition.

The complete logic is then

```
is_recall <- function(data)
{
  bad_ID <- duplicated(your_data$ID)
  bad_attr <- duplicated(your_data$ATTRIBUTE)
  bad_end <- with(your_data, sapply(
    seq_len(nrow(your_data)), 
    function(i) END[i] < min(START[-i] - 100)
  ))
}
```

Comment: DISCLAIMER: No data provided, and logic in question is ambiguous, so there's a high probability of nonsense.